# getting raw layer content using pyshark

Tags: python, parsing, networking, wireshark, pyshark

How can I get the raw layer using pyshark?
For example if a packet has a DNS layer, I would like to get the content of all the feilds in the DNS layer.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iM2oH.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution if someone is interested :)

```
cap = pyshark.FileCapture(cap_path, include_raw=True, use_json=True)
packet = cap[0]
packet_data  = packet[packet.highest_layer].value
```